# how to convert a list of strings into a list of letters in python?

Tags: python, string, list, letter

How do I turn this:

```py
list = ['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is']
```

into this:

```py
list = ['h', 'i', 'm', 'y', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'i', 's']
```

Comment: Have you tried something which is giving you trouble?

Comment: Easy way:  `lst = list(''.join(lst))`

Comment: Don't use builtin as variable names like `list`, `dict`, ...

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953)
|
[Open letter to students with homework problems](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/39188)
|
[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: @KennyOstrom No! Don't use `reduce(add, listofstrings)`. There's a *reason* `sum` (which is the conventional way to do `reduce(add, ...)` ) explicitly throws an error if you try to do this. It's quadratic time. You shoud use `''.join`, which will be linear time

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't really thinking of efficiency. How about [*itertools.chain(*data)] where data is the original list of words?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
l = ['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is']
output = list(''.join(l))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['h', 'i', 'm', 'y', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'i', 's']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the fact that you can iterate over a string just like a list:

```py
words = ['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is']
letters = [letter for word in words for letter in word]
print(letters)
```

Output:

```
['h', 'i', 'm', 'y', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'i', 's']
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited, tip from @juanpa.arrivillaga

```
list = ['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is']

newList = []
for x in list: 
    for y in x: 
        newList.append(y)

print(newList)
```

Output:

```
['h', 'i', 'm', 'y', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'i', 's']
```

Comment: ... ouch.  That’s heavy.

Comment: I wouldn't have downvoted this, but you shouldn't iterate over `range` in Python. Instead, *iterate directly over the sequence*, so use `for string in mylist: for char in string: new_list.append(char)`

Comment: Thankyou @juanpa.arrivillaga for tip